# Can't Deploy Image to Azure App Service via GitHub Actions

Tags: azure-web-app-service, github-actions, azure-web-app-for-containers

I've tried so many different things here, so i'm super excited to see what the issue is :) (but, im assuming it's something silly on my end)

Here's the pertinent bit of my GitHub actions YML:

```
deploy:
    name: Update Azure App Service
    needs: [tests]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
        - name: Deploy to Azure
          uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
          with:
            app-name: $APP_SERVICE_NAME
            images: $IMAGE_NAME
            publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
```

GitHub actions logs (debug mode):

```
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Deploy to Azure'
##[debug]Evaluating: success()
##[debug]Evaluating success:
##[debug]=> true
##[debug]Result: true
##[debug]Starting: Deploy to Azure
##[debug]Loading inputs
##[debug]Evaluating: secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE
##[debug]Evaluating Index:
##[debug]..Evaluating secrets:
##[debug]..=> Object
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE'
##[debug]=> '***'
##[debug]Result: '***'
##[debug]Loading env
Run azure/webapps-deploy@v2
::add-mask::***
::add-mask::***
##[debug][GET] https://SNIP.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/diagnostics/runtime
##[debug]loaded affinity cookie ["ARRAffinity=SNIP;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=SNIP-qa-ause.scm.azurewebsites.net","ARRAffinitySameSite=SNIP;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=SNIP.scm.azurewebsites.net"]
##[debug]getAppRuntime. Data: {"statusCode":200,"statusMessage":"OK","headers":{"connection":"close","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","date":"Fri, 22 Jul 2022 06:27:05 GMT","server":"Kestrel","set-cookie":["ARRAffinity=SNIP;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=app-be-SNIP.scm.azurewebsites.net","ARRAffinitySameSite=SNIP;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=app-be-SNIP.azurewebsites.net"],"transfer-encoding":"chunked"},"body":{"nodejs":[],"system":{"os_name":"Unix 4.15.0.169","os_build_lab_ex":"","cores":2}}}
##[debug]App Runtime OS: Unix 4.15.0.169
Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Error: Publish profile is invalid for app-name and slot-name provided. Provide correct publish profile credentials for app.
##[debug]Deployment failed
##[debug]Node Action run completed with exit code 1
##[debug]AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT='GITHUBACTIONS_DeployWebAppToAzure_0d7e9cbfcd2b52a8a34111a0798ab22d77203fc1f56b2732d2431bfaeb336577'
##[debug]AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT=''
##[debug]Finishing: Deploy to Azure
```

The obvious solution here is what the error says: secret is wrong. It's not. I've added secret to GitHub repository, with the value of the Azure App Service. Done this twice, to make sure i've downloaded it correct, and copied as is.

Other things i've tried:

- Tried setting `WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM` to true in the App Service configuration.
- Tried setting `slot-name` to `Production` in the GitHu action step (even though, there is no slots here)

Other things, that might help solve my problem:

- I'm building a .NET image as a Docker image, and pushing this to Azure Containr Registry. I'm then trying to 'update' this, in Azure App Service
- The Azure App Service is running Linux, not Windows
- "Deployment Center" in App Service still has "Source: Container Registry", pinned to a static image. This is because this was required when i setup App Service. But i *assume* that my GitHub actions builds will override this?

Any help would be great. :) Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I know i can:

- Push to a constant tag, e.g `latest`
- Set the image name to `latest` in Azure App Service
- Set continuous deployment to "on" in Azure App Service

And this will automatically update App Service, because of the webhook.

But this will not help production scenarios, as i need to create different image tags, for different versions i can rollback. Since the version is different, i can't "pin" to a constant tag. Therefore, i need some kind of task to update Azure App Service with a specific tag. I'd prefer to have the same CI for dev/prod.

Comment: Restarting an app service automatically pulls the latest container image from the registry. Which means updating the image in the registry and restarting the App Service should be enough. Unless I'm missing something else you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to do a fully automated deployment. I don't want to manually restart the app service. I also know i can achieve this by doing "Continuous Deployment", but this won't work for production when i want to deploy to staging slot continously, and then make use of Azure auto-swap. Unless i'm misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: Just read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ci-cd-custom-container?tabs=acr&pivots=container-linux#how-cicd-works-with-github-actions) which states that the `webapps-deploy` action (quote) "configures the updated image, which triggers an app restart to pull in the updated image". I thought you weren't using the correct action, but I was wrong.

Comment: It _does_ look like your assumption might not necessarily be correct, so you might want to add a "latest" tag to the image you're using for the app service. This way, pushing a new image with the latest tag will trigger your app service to get the newer image. Still, this probably doesn't solve the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the right action AFAIK. I even compared the generated one from Azure deployment centre to what I have, and it was pretty much the same.

Comment: I can use the "latest" tag approach for dev, but don't work for prod. Prod needs to have different tags, so i can rollback to a previous version. If i tag say "1.0.0.1", i can't do the continuos deployment option as it's not a fixed version, so i'll need "something" to update Azure App Service.